# Im trying to create a menu scene but when i render it, it is kinda dark. How to fix the dark lightning

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As you can see in my Unity scene

[image]

it looks dark.

game tab

[image]

you can see here that it's dark.

I've done going to `window > render > lightning > clear baked data` but its still the same.

Any unity devs can help me, thanks

As you can see in my lightning tab

[image]

`auto generate` is disabled so I can't check it to verify if it can solve my problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Disable your canvas object and if darkness is gone that means there is a dark image in canvas. Find it and disable/remove that object or turn down its' alpha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in the `Canvas` you have an object that has a sprite on it where the color is modified. Also check the alpha setting for the colors there.

Lighting doesn't affect UI elements like that. That only applies to non UIElements like 3D and 2D objects placed in the world (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LightingInUnity.html).

So it's just a sprite that is causing this background color as @Çağatay IŞIK suggested.